# Domino Java Agent running old code after saving

Tags: lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

I'm working on a domino server version 8.5.3 and I am calling a java agent A that makes another java agent B run on the server.  Java agent B references a Java Script Library where most of the code is.

I've chamged the code in the Script Library, saved the script library and the agent separately. There are no compilation errors that I can see.

When I run the code (either directly agent B on the notes cliet or agent A on the server), the old version is running (I know because of a cunning system.out.println()).

It's driving me mad for two hours now. I've tried closing down client and designer, restarting the server, shutting agent manager off and then on, all to no avail.

Is there some magical cache which I could clear?

Comment: As an experiment, you might want to try deleting the script library. (Keep a backup, obviously.)  Then try running the agent and see what happens.

Comment: I had a similar problem when I saved an agent "Script contains errors. would you like to save anyway" and edited it with a different version of Designer. The LAST COMPILED previous version ran and not the one I was editing... I solved this recompiling all my Script lib "bottom up", I mean the one that don't use othing Script Lib first then the one using the immediatly saved one. and so on until the agent itself. And maybe did I re created it by pasting the existing code in the new one.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by starting both the script library and the agent from scratch, renaming everything in the process. What a pain.

Comment: Also, renaming the deepest class (with alt-shift-R) is a good way to see where Domino did'nt get that something changed.